# Can an org table automatically syncronize with another org table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have two `org` tables

```
#+TBLNAME: contact_info
| Name       |  ID | E-Mail          |
|------------+-----+-----------------|
| Washington | 001 | george@usa.pres |
| Adams      | 002 | john@usa.pres   |
| Jefferson  | 003 | thomas@usa.pres |
| Madison    | 004 | james@usa.pres  |

#+TBLNAME: ages
| Name | Age |
|------+-----|
|      |     |
|------+-----|
| Mean |   0 |
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vmean(@<<$2..@>>$2)
```

I would like the first column of `ages` to synchronize with the first column of `contact_info`. In other words, I would like `ages` to look like

```
#+TBLNAME: ages
| Name       | Age |
|------------+-----|
| Washington |     |
| Adams      |     |
| Jefferson  |     |
| Madison    |     |
|------------+-----|
| Mean       |   0 |
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vmean(@<<$2..@>>$2)
```

Furthermore, if I change `contact_info` to

```
#+TBLNAME: contact_info
| Name       |  ID | E-Mail          |
|------------+-----+-----------------|
| Washington | 001 | george@usa.pres |
| Adams      | 002 | john@usa.pres   |
| Madison    | 004 | james@usa.pres  |
| Monroe     | 005 | james1@usa.pres |
| Adams      | 006 | john1@usa.pres  |
```

then I would like `ages` to update to

```
#+TBLNAME: ages
| Name       | Age |
|------------+-----|
| Washington |     |
| Adams      |     |
| Madison    |     |
| Monroe     |     |
| Adams      |     |
|------------+-----|
| Mean       |   0 |
#+TBLFM: @>$2=vmean(@<<$2..@>>$2)
```

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: You can pull data using `remote()` in the formula: http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html, but I don't think there's a way to add or remove rows by means of tables only. However, you could have an Org-babel code block in the document, which outputs a table. If the later will answer your question, please let me know, it's a really simple bit of code though.